# Style WordPress Vertical Navigation Drop Down

Tags: css, wordpress

How can I remove the white border under the  tag from this drop down menu? I only want it to appear when the drop down item is hovered.

Please see for the website. www.velnikolic.com/music Need to type more for limit to go down.

Current CSS

```
/* Navigation --------------------------------------- */
.main-menu li {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 10000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px 70px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}

.main-menu li:hover {
    display: block;
    background:black;
    color:white;
}

.main-menu li:hover  a{     
    color:white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;     
}

ul.main-menu a {
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;  
}

.main-menu > li:first-child { margin-top: 0; }

.main-menu ul { margin-left: 20px; }

.main-menu a { color: #999; 
text-align:center;
}

.main-menu li a:hover,.main-menu li a:focus {
    color:white;
}
.main-menu .current-menu-item > a,
.main-menu .current_page_item > a { color: white; }

li.current-menu-item{
    background:black;
    color:white;
}

.main-menu .current-menu-item:before,
.main-menu .current_page_item:before {
    /*content: '\f405';
    display: block;
    font: 16px/1 "Genericons";
    color: #019EBD;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -20px;*/
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*  User-Added-1. Drop Down Menu
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

ul.sub-menu{
    display: none;
}

li:hover .sub-menu {
    background: #34495e;
    border: #fff solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    top: -1px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "white outline under a tag"?

Answer (score 0):

you must be talking about text decoration property

try this :

text-decoration:none;

possible values are:

none
underline
overline
line-through

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ul.main-menu a
{
    border-bottom: 0;
}

ul.main-menu a
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

EDIT: Try

Changing `.main-menu li:hover a` to `.main-menu li:hover > a`

and add the following:

```
.main-menu li:hover a
{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Let me try to clarify. I added a white border on hover of a <li> item. However, I only want it to show up when you are actually hovering a <li>. It currently shows up on all dropdown menu <li>'s, even if they are not hovered over.
.main-menu li:hover  a{     
    color:white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;     
}